# How to set up and use a development environment for games with graphics on a public computer?

Tags: c++, java

We don't really have any IDEs or development environments with which we could develop games with graphics on school computers. We're on a network run by the school, and can't get technicians to install them, because they're a 'security nightmare' (even though quite a few students can easily circumvent them).

So, what could we do? We'd like to program games in c++ or Java.

Comment: You might want to chose a single language though, as your question is very broad even with only one, asking for 2 languages is really pushing your luck :P

Comment: How locked down are these machines?  Could you plug in a flash drive with portable versions of different software?

Comment: There are said to be decently powerful online game engines (=nothing to install). I have no personal experience with those though.

Comment: Would game development with HTML + JavaScript be an option? You just need a text editor and a web browser.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need IDEs to develop java or c++, you can even write the programs notepad if you're a masochist, but most people use notepad++ as a fallback.

If you want to program in c++, then the only thing you'll need is a compiler (mingw for example). Java however requires the Java enviroment and the Java developement kit (JDK).

None of these can actually cause a security problem though (expect maybe java, if you get a java-based virus, but believe me, you won't). They don't connect to the internet, and what could a virus do with the C++ compiler or the JDK?

Comment: "what could a virus do with the C++ compiler" - infect any programs made with it and spread itself to other computers that way.

Comment: Sounds like someone may want to re-read [Reflections on Trusting Trust](https://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ganger/712.fall02/papers/p761-thompson.pdf). ;)

Comment: @LeComte If the virus really wants to make programs, then he could either bring them in bytecode form or just use a self-provided gcc compiler